# When i m selecting any option from dropdown list it is not getting selected and how to keep dropdown from closing while click on textbox?

Tags: drop-down-menu

here is my dropdown:

**Select Folder**

Folder 1

Folder 2

in this dropdown when i click on textbox it closes automatically.
Also auto-close="disabled" not working.
And also when i select any option from the dropdown it should come in place of select folder but its not happening.

Comment: the third one should be a textbox to create new folder

Comment: What programming language are we working with?  The answers will differ *just a bit* depending on the language.